# If apiece of wood furniture is varnished, can i just paint right over it?

Tags: wooden-furniture, varnishing

If apiece of wood furniture is varnished, can i just paint right over it or any special advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sheen of the varnish needs to come off first.  That can be done best in my opinion with sand paper, 175-grit would be good.

Comment: And then I'd still use a good bonding primer.